# LaTeX/Math jokes

Tags: math-mode, graphics, fun

Lighten up a bit guys. How about the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
If~~$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow8}\frac{1}{x{-}8}=\infty$
~~then~~$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow5}\frac{1}{x{-}5}=\rotatebox{90}{5}$
\end{document}
```

Which gives —
[image]

Can anyone give me some nice Tikz of PStricks code for the following
[image]

I am sure there there must be more Latex humor out there, even among the Germans ;-)

Comment: To avoid this becoming simply a rehash of the AMS article, may I add the proviso that TeX has to be non-trivially involved in the joke (as is the case in the two examples given).

Comment: I made it CW because it asks about more contributions which wouldn't fit in the normal Q&A scheme.

Comment: @Danie: You should add any new examples that you think of as answers rather than editing the question.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey, Yes I'll do that

Comment: 1+1=3 for sufficient large 1s and sufficient small 3s.

Comment: @Martin: That's _exactly_ the sort of thing I'd like this place to avoid.  (Though I did once have a friend who said "As 5 -> 0 ..." with a straight face.)

Comment: Long live South Park ;)

Comment: For the first example I think `\rotatebox{-90}{5}` is more correct. Notice where the heavier stroke of the `8` and `\infty` fall. Yes I am a pedant.

Comment: @Lev: Actually you need a reflection.

Comment: Can I please change the first sentence a bit?  The way I read it, there is a hidden implication that we take ourselves too seriously here on TeX-SX.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I've started using Latex way back in the previous millennium. The one thing that I have seen everywhere, here, CTT, other newsgroups is that we are taking ourselves way to serious. This is the first time through all the years that I have seen postings on latex humor. History in the making and you are part of it ;-)

Comment: @Danie: This is the first TeX-like group that I've joined and I've found it to have a good atmosphere.  Serious enough that we don't get overwhelmed with silly stuff, but not so serious that we can't enjoy ourselves (for example, I note that your question has only one downvote).  Your first sentence reads (to me): "Everyone here is so serious.  Let's lighten up a bit!".  I would have written something more neutral, such as "They say that humour is a great way to learn.  So let's have some examples of TeX humour.  Things like ..."

Comment: @Danie: (Probably worth noting that I cut my teeth on MathOverflow where we _do_ take ourselves _very_ seriously.)

Comment: Since this starts to attract lots of negatively voted answers, I vote to close the question.

Comment: @Caramdir: We will never find this bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93093/151752 without many negatively voted responses.

Comment: I've also voted to close now.  The idea I had was that the "jokes" should reveal something about TeX, such as illustrating a technique.  Some answers did that, but the longer the question stays open then the less likely it is that new answers will continue in that vein.  So while I enjoyed it when it was asked, I think that it had a finite life and it is now time to close it.

Comment: This topic did not explain the rules from the beginning. I thought that we have to make a joke of mathematics using LaTeX. Or make a joke of mathematics without using LaTeX. Or make a joke of LaTeX without associating it with math. This topic has been subjective since the beginning and we are late to close it. Obviously there are benefits that can be learned. :)

Comment: [Code](http://pastebin.com/FjKDw5NG) and [Output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzhH.gif)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about:

```
\font\donteveruseoutsidecartoons="Comic Sans MS" at 14pt
\font\donteveruseoutsidecartoonstwo="Comic Sans MS/IB:slant=.3pt" at 22pt
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,positioning}
\tikzpicture[mycallout/.style={draw,ellipse callout,inner sep=1.2ex,
    callout relative pointer={#1}}]
  \node[mycallout={(.5cm,-.5cm)}] (ico) {\donteveruseoutsidecartoons Be rational};
  \node[mycallout={(-.5cm,-.5cm)}, right=of ico] (pco) {\donteveruseoutsidecartoons Get real};
  \node[below=.1ex of ico.pointer] {\donteveruseoutsidecartoonstwo i};
  \node[below left=.1ex of pco.pointer] {\donteveruseoutsidecartoonstwo π\vphantom(};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: _especially_ for the font names

Comment: This is very good.  People may not realize it, but all this stuff is very usefull to make boring engineering or math lectures a little bit more interesting.

Comment: @Danie: Completely agree.  And often (speaking as a lecturer) it's not until I see an example that I realise that such things are possible so there is certainly potential value in this question.

Comment: –1 for the font. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad --- surely that should be `\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}` for the font?

Answer (score 37):

I was laughing about this one quite a bit. I had to recall it from German and translate it. Feel free to adjust the language.

[image: 500random]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\large\sffamily

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{The first 500 natural random numbers}

\vspace{1em}

\centerline{\LARGE For easy access listed in their natural order}
\bigskip

\par\noindent
\foreach \n in {1,...,500} {%
    \makebox[1.8em][r]{\n}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Martin Scharrer - I like this. Do you mind if I turn it into a natural number spotter's guide and stick it on wall?

Comment: @Richard: Sure. Note I didn't came up with it. I saw this in my college in the math building once.

Answer (score 37):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Expand $(a+b)^n$:
\begin{gather*}
  (a + b)^n\\
  (a\ + \ b)^n\\
  (a\quad + \quad b)^n\\
  (a\qquad + \qquad b)^n
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: to Andrew:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\mycntr

\begin{document}

Expand $(a+b)^n$:

\begin{center}
  \mycntr=0
  \loop\advance\mycntr by 1
  \ifnum\mycntr<40
    $(a\hskip\mycntr pt +\hskip\mycntr pt b)^n$\\
  \repeat
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is epic.

Comment: Aw, come on ... no iteration?  Let's have a more _programmatic_ version of this one!

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: done. Personally I prefer the non-iterative version.

Comment: I prefer expanding the expression in 2 dimension.

Answer (score 33):

A silly one I found on [a blog](http://jacksmix.wordpress.com/2007/05/30/some-funny-math-jokes/):

[image: six]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \frac{1}{n}\sin x & = & \mathrm{?} \\
    \frac{1}{\cancel{n}} \mathrm{si}\cancel{\mathrm{n}} ~x & = & \mathrm{?} \\
    \mathrm{six} & = & 6
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

This one from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/184/) is a classic:

[image: transform]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos 90^{\circ} & \sin 90^{\circ}\\
   -\sin 90^{\circ} & \cos 90^{\circ}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a1 \\ a2 \end{bmatrix}
=
$
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{$\begin{bmatrix} a1 \\ a2 \end{bmatrix}$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32):

I never played with `tikz` before, so that's my first attempt. I simply love the following joke:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\begin{document}

Find $x$.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) node[midway,below] {4 cm}
   -- (4,3) node[midway,right] {3 cm}
   -- (0,0) node[midway,left,circle,draw=blue,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=0.5pt}]{$x$}
   -- (4,0) rectangle (3.7,0.3)
   -- cycle;
\draw (0.4,0) arc (0:30:0.5);
\draw (4,2.6) arc (270:226:0.5);
\draw (1,2.1) node []{\color{blue}\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont{It's here!}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Find x.]

Comment: You should also draw a blue circle around *x*. Just add `circle,draw=blue` to its node. I might need to set the color of the content back to black.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks a lot, I updated both code and image. It looks way better that way! =)

Comment: The circle could use a jittering line (it’s hand-drawn, right?). You can use the `random steps` decoration for that.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Thanks, I updated the code again. You guys are awesome! =)

Comment: A pedant's note: you could use a `\,` or `\SI` from `siunitx` to typeset the lengths.

Answer (score 16):

Mathematicians do it in `\LaTeX`.

I'll get my coat.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jplOL.jpg

Answer (score 12):

To all my Australian friends:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent Are there any \raisebox{1ex}{\rotatebox[origin=B]{180}{Australians}}
here mate?\\ Hang on tight!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's another joke I remember:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[light,math]{anttor}

\begin{document}

Let $\displaystyle f(a) = \sqrt[n]{e^x}$.

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{eqnarray*}
      \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} f(a) - \frac{i}{f(t)} & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u) \\
      \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} f(a) - \frac{i}{\infty} & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u) \\
      \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} f(a) - 0 & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u)
   \end{eqnarray*}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

Then

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{eqnarray*}
      \sqrt[n]{e^x} & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u) \\
      (\sqrt[n]{e^x})^n & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u)^n \\
      e^x & = & \frac{d}{dx} f(u)^n \\
      \int e^x & = & f(u)^n
   \end{eqnarray*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: You naughty equation!]

Comment: You deliberately made many typos?

Comment: Sadly, no. I simply wrote it _as it is_ from a PNG image. =)

Answer (score 3):

Riffing on the "Australians" joke, borrowing from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/rotating-a-letter/18160#18160).

[image: Any Australians here?]

Comment: I get the original joke, but fail to see it in the alternations.

Comment: @Martin it's my tribute to [Stewart Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_Lee)