# Bad intersection of lines in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 4]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\draw (a) -- (intersection of a--b and b--c);
\draw (c) -- (intersection of a--b and b--c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How can I fill the corner? Adding `[cap=rounded]` didn't solve the issue. I know that I could do something like `\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c)` but I *need* to obtain the same effect using intersection.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** I try to figure out how to handle two *independent* line segments and their intersection. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line width=7]
\coordinate (a1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (b2) at (1,-1);
\draw (b1) -- (b2);
\foreach \x in {0,20,30,40,45}
{
\coordinate (a2) at (\x:10);
\draw (a1) -- (intersection of a1--a2 and b1--b2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here, I don't know in advance (well I do, but for the sake of the question I don't), where the two segments intersect and whether or not the intersection point is a common end point.

[image]

Comment: As Jake says in the comments to his answer, could you give a slightly more complicated example of what you are trying to do?  If your lines meet at right-angles then you could add `line cap=rect` to make it look right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get the corner right, the path should be drawn in a single `\draw` command. You can still use the `intersection of` in this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 4]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate (c) at (1,1);
\draw (a) -- (intersection of a--b and b--c) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed helpful for my case, but in general I think it is not good enough. If you're plotting something with parameters, then you may not know in advance that the intersection occurs exactly at a corner. It may be some mid point or a proper intersection. Is there some more general approach?

Comment: @Dror: Could you edit your example to include a case like the one you mention? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "proper intersection".

Comment: @Dror: Ah, do you mean that your two lines would not necessarily use the same `intersection` as their endpoints?

Comment: @Jake: Yes - more or less. Consider my edit...

Comment: When I drew [this triangle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/latex-math-jokes/18354#18354), I read in the `Tikz` manual that I should close the triangle with `--cycle`.

Comment: @Paulo: Yes, that's correct, but it's not relevant here, because the OP is not trying to get a closed shape, but only to connect two lines correctly.

Comment: @Jake: Oh my bad, just thought it would work as well. =)

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is most likely best handled by a `clip` to chop the lines extending from `(a1)` at the edge of the line they are meant to be drawn to.  Getting it right is a bit of a hassle (but would be near impossible without the fantastic `calc` library) and the following is not guaranteed to be anywhere near robust.  I've tried not to assume that your lines are aligned with the axes, but I was only careful at getting the clip path right on the line from `(b1)` to `(b2)`.

Incidentally, this doesn't interact well with the `scale` option since that scales coordinates but not line widths.  So to enlarge your picture I used the `x=4cm,y=4cm` syntax which redefines the standard unit.

[image: line ends]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=7,y=4cm,x=4cm]
\coordinate (a1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (b2) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (ab) at ($($(b1)!(a1)!(b2)$)!-.5\pgflinewidth!(a1)$);
\coordinate (ab1) at ($(b1)!(ab)!90:(b2)$);
\coordinate (ab2) at ($(b2)!(ab)!90:(b1)$);
\draw[red] (b1) -- (b2);
\clip ($(ab1)!-1cm!(ab2)$) -- ($(ab2)!-1cm!(ab1)$) -| (a1) |-  ($(ab1)!-1cm!(ab2)$);
\foreach \x in {0,20,30,40,45}
{
\coordinate (a2) at (\x:10);
\draw (a1) -- ($(a1)!1.1!(intersection of a1--a2 and b1--b2)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to (re)draw the corners as part of a continuous path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line width=7]
 \coordinate (a1) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (b1) at (1,1);
 \coordinate (b2) at (1,-1);
 \coordinate (a0) at (0:10);
 \draw (b1) -- (b2) ;
 \foreach \x in {0,20,30,40,45}
 {
 \coordinate (a2) at (\x:10);
 \draw (a1) -- (intersection of a1--a2 and b1--b2) -- (b2);
 }

 \draw (b1) -- (a1) -- (intersection of a1--a0 and b1--b2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a brilliant solution and I've stolen it for another answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along/18717#18717