# How to fix TikZ corners in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf

Am trying to draw a simple rectangle and there seems to be minor issue with two of the endpoints (**f** and **d** in the following). I tried `line cap=rect` as suggested by [Bad intersection of lines in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/bad-intersection-of-lines-in-tikz) but that did not seem to work.  The resulting image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\Width}{2.0}
\newcommand*{\Height}{3.0}
\newcommand*{\Depth}{1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \coordinate (A) at ( 0,       0,     \Depth);%
    \coordinate (B) at (\Height,  0,     \Depth);%
    \coordinate (C) at (\Height,  0,      0);%
    \coordinate (D) at (\Height, \Width,  0);%
    \coordinate (E) at ( 0,      \Width,  0);%
    \coordinate (F) at ( 0,      \Width, \Depth);%
    \coordinate (G) at (\Height, \Width, \Depth);%
    \coordinate (H) at ( 0,       0,      0);%
    %
    \draw [blue, ultra thick,line cap=rect]%
        (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;%
    \draw [blue, ultra thick,line cap=rect]%
        (B) -- (G) -- (F) -- (E) -- (D) -- (G) -- cycle;%

    \path (D)  [right] node {$d$};% Problem Point 1
    \path (F)  [left ] node {$f$};% Problem Point 2
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

This problem about [TikZ: changing colour of a path half way along](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along/18717#18717) seems related, but I do not understand how to adapt that to my problem.

Comment: Can you include the picture?

Comment: Have added a link to the image.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use a different `line join` type here, either `round` or `bevel`, which influences how the corner (not the ends) of lines are drawn:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=miter] % Standard option
```

[image: miter joins]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]
```

[image: bevel joins]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
```

[image: round joins]

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks. So is there a reason why I would not want to always use line join=round? I have posted a follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/in-tikz-when-is-line-join-miter-the-preferrable-over-line-join-round

Comment: @PeterGrill: If possible, `line join=round` is probably best. However, it is not always possible depending on how you construct your diagram, I guess.

Comment: @Werner: According to Jake in the question [is line join miter the preferable over line join round](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/in-tikz-when-is-line-join-miter-the-preferrable-over-line-join-round) the `miter` option should be used unless otherwise needed as is the case here.