# Unpleasant Gaps in the corners

Tags: pstricks

In the following MWE, there are some unpleasant gaps. I would like to produce a "smooth" line as drawn with the use of pswedge (which isn't working for the lower chart). How can I do that?



[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](1,-2.5)(6,1.5)
\psset{algebraic=true}
\pswedge[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,0.25){2cm}{0}{180}
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](1.5,-0.25)(5.5,-0.25)
\psarc[linewidth=1.5pt](3.2,-0.25){1.7cm}{180}{330}
\psarc[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,-0.25){2cm}{-30}{0}
\SpecialCoor
\rput(3.5,-0.25){\pnode(2cm;-30){A}}
\rput(3.2,-0.25){\pnode(1.7cm;-30){B}}
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `tikz` there is the option `line joint` -- maybe there is something similar in ´pstricks´ or you switch to ´tikz´ (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21063 for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the last commands in a `\pscustom`, and set `linejoin=1`. I took the opportunity to simplify your preamble: needless to load `pstricks` if you load `pst-node`. `SpecialCoor` is no more necessary, as it is set by default nowadays. Note also that `pstricks` loads `xcolor`. I added `auto-pst-pdf`, which enables to compile with  `pdflatex` if you add to the compiler launching command the `-shell-escape` switch under TeX Live and MacTeX, `--enable-write18`  under MiKTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](1,-2.5)(6,1.5)
    \psset{algebraic=true, linejoin=1}
    \pswedge[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,0.25){2cm}{0}{180}
    \psset{linecolor = red}
    \pscustom[linewidth=1.5pt]{
        \psline(1.5,-0.25)(5.5,-0.25)
        \psarc(3.2,-0.25){1.7cm}{180}{330}
        \psarc[](3.5,-0.25){2cm}{-30}{0}}
    \rput(3.5,-0.25){\pnode(2cm;-30){A}}
    \rput(3.2,-0.25){\pnode(1.7cm;-30){B}}
    \psline[linewidth=1.5pt](A)(B)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Somewhere I read about the \closepath command ... Is it necessary to use it (here)?

Comment: It does not seem to change whatever. Oh, by the way: `\SpecialCoord` is no more necessary nowadays: it is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Without `\pscustom`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,-2.5)(6,1.5)
    \pswedge[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,0.25){2cm}{0}{180}
    \psline[linewidth=1.5pt](1.5,-0.25)(5.5,-0.25)
    \psset{linecap=1}%%%%%%   !!!!  %%%%%%
    \psarc[linewidth=1.5pt](3.2,-0.25){1.7cm}{180}{330}
    \psarc[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,-0.25){2cm}{-30}{0}
    \pnode[3.5,-0.25](2cm;-30){A}
    \pnode[3.2,-0.25](1.7cm;-30){B}
    \psline[linewidth=1.5pt](A)(B)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or *with* `\pscustom`:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,-2.5)(6,1.5)
\pswedge[linewidth=1.5pt](3.5,0.25){2cm}{0}{180}
\pscustom[linewidth=1.5pt,linejoin=1]{%
    \psarc(3.2,-0.25){1.7cm}{180}{330}
    \psarc[](3.5,-0.25){2cm}{-30}{0}
    \closepath%  to get the horizontal line
}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]