# How can I fix extruded polygon corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm working with tkz-euclide and I'm having a problem with the corners of each inscribed triangle sticking out of the circumference of the circle. This is what it looks like:
[image: Uh oh!]

... and this is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/P, 3/0/R}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,P)
\tkzDrawPoint(O)
\tkzLabelPoints(O)

\foreach \i in {0,...,2}
{
    \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i ,center=O,radius=3]
    \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i + 120,center=O,radius=3]
    \tkzGetPoint{R}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20!white](O,P,R)
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I understand this is only a small bit of detail, but I would like to know how I can fix this in case other people have this problem too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Isn't it compilable? You could just copy and paste the code between the \begin{document} and \end{document} tags, and don't forget to import the tkz-euclide package right?

Comment: Yes I could do that. But YOU should do that.

Comment: @hpekristiansen alright, I'll include the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is probable a duplicate. You can change the `line join` to a type that is more suitable - see: [In TikZ when is "line join=miter" the preferrable over "line join=round"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/in-tikz-when-is-line-join-miter-the-preferrable-over-line-join-round)

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/P, 3/0/R}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,P)
\tkzDrawPoint(O)
\tkzLabelPoints(O)

\foreach \i in {0,...,2}
{
    \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i ,center=O,radius=3]
    \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i + 120,center=O,radius=3]
    \tkzGetPoint{R}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20!white, line join=round](O,P,R)
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle and triangle with Better line loints]

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should adapt the join type:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/P, 3/0/R}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,P)
        \tkzDrawPoint(O)
        \tkzLabelPoints(O)
        
        \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
        {
            \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i ,center=O,radius=3]
            \tkzGetPoint{P}
            \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=120*\i + 120,center=O,radius=3]
            \tkzGetPoint{R}
            \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20!white,line join=bevel](O,P,R)
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```