# How can I draw these polygons with shaded regions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, shading

I don't know how to draw this by LaTeX.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? There are only a few things to deal with here: 1. Define the points with `\coordinate (A1) at (<x>,<y>);`. 2. Label the nodes: `\node at (A1) {$A_1$};`. 3. Draw the lines: `\draw (A1) -- (A2)`, etc.  all within a `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`.  The only part left that does require work is the shading and you can use the `intersections` library to help with that.

Comment: Once you get the basic structure, then you can use a `\foreach` loop to allow you to have one reusable diagram where you can just specify the number of vertices you want and the rest gets computed automatically. But first you need to do the manual diagram to be able to get started.

Comment: Try reading the `pgf` manual. In your terminal write `texdoc pgf`. Of particular interest maybe section `2.16`

Comment: @lockstep: I feel that it is a problem that you and other high end users urge others not to post 'do this for me' questions - without any real power behind. Someone always do the work, and thereby encourage this behavior. -this is obviously not your fault, but maybe you can do something about the problem!? vote to close the question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

### The first diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    % declare the points, specify the labels and the labels' positions.
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90,0,-30,-90,-135}]
        (0,4){A_1}
        (3,6){A_2}
        (6,4){A_3}
        (5.5,2){A_4}
        (2,0){A_5}
        (0,0.5){A_n}
    % specify the intersection point between line A1A3 and A2A4, name the intersection point I.
    \pstInterLL[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{A_1}{A_3}{A_2}{A_4}{I}
    % fill the inner region
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines](A_1)(I)(A_4)
    % construct the remaining inner lines
    \pstLineAB{A_2}{I}% you can also use \psline{A_2}{I} instead.
    \pstLineAB{A_3}{I}% you can also use \psline{A_3}{I} instead.
    % construct the outer lines
    \psline
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_5}A_n)
        (A_n)
        (A_1)
        (A_2)
        (A_3)
        (A_4)
        (A_5)
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_5)
    % construct a dashed line
    \psline[linestyle=dashed]
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_5)
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_5}A_n)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The construction steps are summarized as follows,

[image]

### The second diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90,0,0,-30,-90,-135}]
        (0,4){A_1}
        (3,6){A_2}
        (5,5){A_3}
        (6,3){A_4}
        (4.5,1.5){A_5}
        (2,0){A_6}
        (0,0){A_n}
    % fill the inner regions with even-odd rule.
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=gray](A_1)(A_4)(A_2)(A_5)(A_3)
    \psline(A_1)(A_5)
    \psline
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_6}A_n)
        (A_n)
        (A_1)
        (A_2)
        (A_3)
        (A_4)
        (A_5)
        (A_6)
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_6)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed]
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_6)
        ([nodesep=5pt]{A_6}A_n)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The construction steps are summarized as follows,

[image]

### The last diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{multido,fp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-3)(3,3)
    % declare the points, specify the labels and the labels' positions.
    \multido{\n=180+45,\i=1+1}{7}{\pstGeonode[PosAngle=-\n](3;-\n){A_\i}}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-135](3;-135){A_n}
    \pscustom
    {
        \moveto([nodesep=5pt]{A_7}A_n)
        \lineto(A_n)
        \multido{\i=1+1}{7}{\lineto(A_\i)}
        \lineto([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_7)
    }
    \psline[linestyle=dashed]([nodesep=5pt]{A_n}A_7)([nodesep=5pt]{A_7}A_n)
    % specify the intersection points.
    \bgroup
        \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
        \pstInterLL{A_1}{A_4}{A_2}{A_5}{P}
        \pstInterLL{A_1}{A_4}{A_3}{A_6}{Q}
        \pstInterLL{A_2}{A_5}{A_3}{A_6}{R}
    \egroup
    % fill the shaded region.
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow](P)(Q)(R)
    % construct the remaining lines.
    \multido{\ix=1+1}{4}
    {
        \FPeval\N{round(5-\ix:0)}
        \FPeval\Start{round(\ix+2:0)}
        \multido{\iy=\Start+1}{\N}{\psline(A_\ix)(A_\iy)}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've got the following message "This version uses the pst-xkey package for managing parameters
 Please read the doc, some macros have a new syntax
 use option old for upward compatibility c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex". But afer 30sec the diagrams were drawn.

Comment: @AdorableCreature It wasn't me.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: [OK](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/who-wants-to-win-a-latex-book?page=5&tab=votes#comment8645_3099).

Comment: Oh, I missed this this question getting bumped into Bounty Questions. Wouldn't an edit in the title be enough, say make it more general since that is how the body of the question was phrased? I don't think the OP will want to edit the question since it is the OP's only question and OP has not been active since Nov 17, 2012. `:)`

Comment: @hpesoj626: Do you have idea to rephrase the title to be more specific or unique?

Comment: @AdorableCreature Well, you can ask in meta but I would suggest *How Can I Draw this Diagram in LaTeX* or *How Can I Draw this Diagram in Tikz/PSTricks*.

Comment: @hpesoj626: the words "this diagram" seems to be too general so any questions can reuse it.

Comment: @AdorableCreature "How Can I Draw these polygons with shaded regions"? I have no more idea. You can around chat I think.

Answer (score 23):

It will benefit you more if you read the [`pgf` manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), especially if you have to draw more of these figures in the future. The manual gives detailed examples on how to use `tikz` to draw your LaTeX figures.

I assume that you have some knowledge of LaTeX. If you don't, then, on this site, you may start with [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex).

Let's start with some `tikz` basics and fit them with your question.

We will use your first figure in this demonstration. We can assign coordinates by using the `\coordinate` command. We can automate the assigning of coordinates but we shall not do that for the vertices of the polygon. We can type something like the following for the first three vertices:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that if you try to compile your document, no figure will appear. Don't worry, you have just assigned the coordinates but you have not done anything to tell `tikz` to draw your figure.

You can  now draw a segment connecting `(A1)` to `(A2)` and `(A2)` to `(A3)` by writing `\draw (A1) -- (A2);` and `\draw (A2)--(A3);`. So you now have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\draw (A1) -- (A2);
\draw (A2)--(A3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or alternatively, you can write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\draw (A1) -- (A2)--(A3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and you get the following figure.

[image]

To draw the labels, you have to use the `\node` command with the proper positioning options like `left, right, below, above, above left, above, right, below left, below right` as in the following code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\draw (A1) -- (A2);
\draw (A2) -- (A3);
\node [left] at (A1) {$A_1$};
\node [above] at (A2) {$A_2$};
\node [right] at (A3) {$A_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives you

[image]

Here is the polygon with labels.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (3,-1.5);
\coordinate (A5) at (1.5,-2.5);
\coordinate (An) at (0,-1.5);
\draw (An) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5);
\draw [dashed] (A5) -- (An);
\node [left] at (A1) {$A_1$};
\node [above] at (A2) {$A_2$};
\node [right] at (A3) {$A_3$};
\node [right] at (A4) {$A_4$};
\node [below] at (A5) {$A_5$};
\node [left] at (An) {$A_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

We can determine the intersection with

```
\path [name path = A2--A4,draw] (A2) -- (A4);
\path [name path = A1--A3,draw] (A1) -- (A3);
\coordinate [name intersections={of= A1--A3 and A2--A4,by=intersect-1}]; % the intersection is named *intersect-1*
```

To add the shading we write

```
\shade (A1) -- (intersect-1) -- (A4) -- cycle;
```

Putting it all together we have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (3,-1.5);
\coordinate (A5) at (1.5,-2.5);
\coordinate (An) at (0,-1.5);
\draw (A1) -- (A4);
\draw (An) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5);
\draw [dashed] (A5) -- (An);
\node [left] at (A1) {$A_1$};
\node [above] at (A2) {$A_2$};
\node [right] at (A3) {$A_3$};
\node [right] at (A4) {$A_4$};
\node [below] at (A5) {$A_5$};
\node [left] at (An) {$A_n$};
% determine the intersection and apply the shading
\path [name path = A2--A4,draw] (A2) -- (A4);
\path [name path = A1--A3,draw] (A1) -- (A3);
\coordinate [name intersections={of= A1--A3 and A2--A4,by=intersect-1}];
\shade (A1) -- (intersect-1) -- (A4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

We can shorten the code by using `\foreach` and a technique for placing the nodes that I learned from Peter Grill. Note

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1.5,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (3,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (3,-1.5);
\coordinate (A5) at (1.5,-2.5);
\coordinate (An) at (0,-1.5);
\coordinate (center) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A4)$);
% Draw the sides of the polygon
\draw (An) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5);
\draw [dashed] (A5) -- (An);
% draw nodes
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,n}
    \coordinate (AO\x) at ($(A\x)-(center)$); % defines the coordinates relative to the (center) coordinate.
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,n}
    \node at ($(center)+1.15*(AO\x)$) {$A_{\x}$}; % You can tweak 1.5 into a value that suits you.
\path [name path = A2--A4,draw] (A2) -- (A4);
\path [name path = A1--A3,draw] (A1) -- (A3);
\coordinate [name intersections={of= A1--A3 and A2--A4,by=intersect-1}];
\shade (A1) -- (intersect-1) -- (A4) -- cycle;
\draw (A1) -- (A4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice tutorial. Not sure mine adds much value.

Comment: @PeterGrill see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 16):

For this type of diagram you really need to consider what the goal is. How much flexibility do you want to have:

- Are those *all* the diagrams of this kind that you want drawn?
- Do you want to be able to chose the line styles of each edge?
- How do you want to specify which regions are shaded?

Questions like this will have an effect on the final solution.  But before you can even begin to think about adding flexibility you need to be able to draw one of them.  Here I have used fixed points so that this is easier to follow, but once you understand how this works, you can  come up with an algorithm to automate this further perhaps generating the locations of the points.

1. **Define the points:**

   Best to first define all the coordinates we need using the `\coordinate (<node_name>)at (<x>,<y>)` syntax  so that we can easily makes changes later if needed.

   ```
   \coordinate (A1) at (0,4);
   \coordinate (A2) at (3,6);
       ...
   ```
2. **Label the nodes:**

   To label the points we place a `node` at each vertex:

   ```
   \node [left ] at (A1) {$A_1$};
   \node [above] at (A2) {$A_2$};
       ...
   ```

   Hmm, this seems a bit tedious to list out all the points.  The only thing different between each node, is where it is placed relative to the point and the label. So, we can use a `\foreach` to simplify things:

   ```
   \foreach \Index/\Position in {1/left, 2/above, 3/above right, 4/right, 5/below right, 6/below, n/left} {
       \node [\Position] at (A\Index) {$A_{\Index}$};
   }%
   ```
3. **Draw the Lines:**

   To draw the lines we simply connect each of the points:

   ```
   \draw (An) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5) -- (A6);
   ```

   The draw command accepts an optional parameter to control the line styles. For the dotted line we provide the `dotted` option:

   ```
   \draw [dotted] (An) -- (A6);
   ```

   So, now we have the basic shape:

   [image]

   Similarly, draw the other lines:

   ```
   \draw [gray, ultra thick] 
       (A1) -- (A3)
       (A2) -- (A4)
       (A1) -- (A4);
   ```

   [image]
4. **Intersections:**

   To automatically determine the points of intersections you could use the `intersections` library.

   ```
   \fill [fill=red!20, draw=black, ultra thick, name intersections={of=A1A3 and A2A4}]
       (A1) -- (intersection-1) -- (A4) -- cycle;
   ```

   which yields:

   [image]
5. **Non-Solid Line Style:**

   As was pointed out in the comments, the included images had a combination dashed/dotted line. You could define a custom style for that (which would warrant a separate question), but you could also use the tikz's `calc` library to compute points in between the last point and `An`:

   ```
   \coordinate (An') at ($(An)!0.30!(A6)$);%  30% along the path from An to A6
   \coordinate (A6') at ($(A6)!0.30!(An)$);%  30% along the path from A6 to An
   ```

   Here I have used points 30% of the way along the path to switch from dotted to dashed. 
   The color highlighting makes this change more apparent and also makes it more obvious which parts of the code produce what:

   ```
   \draw [ultra thick, blue,   densely dashed] (An)  -- (An');
   \draw [ultra thick, orange, loosely dotted] (An') -- (A6');
   \draw [ultra thick, blue,   densely dashed] (A6') -- (A6);
   ```

   [image]

### Notes:

- To fix the corners of the black triangle in the earlier pictures I added the option `line join=round` as per [How to fix TikZ corners in 3D](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21054/how-to-fix-tikz-corners-in-3d).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define all the points:
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,4);
    \coordinate (A2) at (3,6);
    \coordinate (A3) at (5,5);
    \coordinate (A4) at (6,3);
    \coordinate (A5) at (4.5,1.5);
    \coordinate (A6) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (An) at (0,0);

% Draw the lines
    \draw [ultra thick, blue, solid ] (An) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5) -- (A6);

    \coordinate (An') at ($(An)!0.30!(A6)$);%  30% along the path from An to A6
    \coordinate (A6') at ($(A6)!0.30!(An)$);%  30% along the path from A6 to An
    \draw [ultra thick, blue,   densely dashed] (An)  -- (An');
    \draw [ultra thick, orange, dotted        ] (An') -- (A6');
    \draw [ultra thick, blue,   densely dashed] (A6') -- (A6);

% Label the nodes:
    \foreach \Index/\Position in {1/left, 2/above, 3/above right, 4/right, 5/below right, 6/below, n/left} {
        \node [\Position] at (A\Index) {$A_{\Index}$};
    }%

    \draw [gray, ultra thick] 
            [name path=A1A3] (A1) -- (A3)
            [name path=A2A4] (A2) -- (A4)
            [name path=A1A4] (A1) -- (A4);

    \fill [fill=red!20, draw=black, line join=round, ultra thick, name intersections={of=A1A3 and A2A4}]
        (A1) -- (intersection-1) -- (A4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was also thinking along the lines of `\Index/\Position` but my shortsightedness/inexperience got the better of me. :)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Was not sure if a `dashed` or `dotted` line was required.  The default `dotted` is as above. I think a custom line style is probably called for based on the given image, but that is a different matter and perhaps warrants a separate question if it is desired.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: Have updated solution for that.

Answer (score 11):

Use any of these two examples as a basis, provided by TeXample:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/polygon-division/ (Eric Détrez)

[image: polygon]

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cn4-points-of-intersection/ (Hugues Vermeiren)

[image: cn4]