# How to draw these (closed contours) diagrams using TikZ or PSTricks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

First, I must say I have no knowledge about PGF/TikZ nor PSTricks, but I would like to draw the following or similar closed contours using one of them or another adequate package. Where can I find the TikZ and the PSTricks manuals?
I would appreciate if you could indicate the code to draw one of the diagrams.

ADDED: I've found [this](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) TikZ Manual for Version 2.10. It coincides with the package version installed on my computer, as I checked after the help of Benedikt Bauer's comments.

**Diagram A**

[image]

**Diagram B**

[image]

Comment: The TikZ documentation itself contains some very nice tutorials. One of them is alreay quite close to what you want to do. As it has been installed with your TeX distribution it should be enough to enter ``texdoc tikz`` (or, if this shouldn't work ``texdoc pgf``) into a text mode console window on your computer. Alternatively you can just take your favourite search engine to search for ``pgfmanual``. But be aware that you could get a version this way that won't fit the version installed in your TeX system.

Comment: I think you should first try by yourself and the post the code. The forum generally helps to fix the mistakes in the code, but rarely to write the entire code.

Comment: @RajTendulkar Well, you may be quite right, but I noticed that the recent question [How to draw this diagram with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78039/how-to-draw-this-diagram-with-tikz) was answered even without indication of the code by the OP.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Many thanks for the information. I have installed `TeX Live` recently and up to now I've only used the editor TeXworks.  Where should I enter `texdoc tikz` or `texdoc pgf`?

Comment: @BenediktBauer In the meantime I've found [this](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) TikZ Manual for Version 2.10.

Comment: @AméricoTavares You are indeed right about the cases that sometimes even though we are trying to push the askers to give us at least an MWE some questions get answered without a MWE. We are hoping that this would not encourage the users to post more and more *do-it-for-me* questions. The main problem is to create a problem set up from scratch just to answer each question and if you can provide the bare minimal people can directly copy/paste your base MWE and directly attack the problem instead of trying to fix many boring prerequisites (also some are too tempting to answer, like yours :) ).

Comment: @AméricoTavares: as already pointed out in my first comment there's a drawback with taking package documentations from the web: The Version of the documentation does not necessarily fit to the package version installed on your computer. In most cases this does no harm, but if the package has had some heavy development between the two versions, some things maybe wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: If you are on a windows system, hit ``Windows+R`` keys and in the window that is popping up, enter the commands. On a Linux desktop ``Alt+F2`` should bring up a similar dialogue.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Many thanks! I'm working on Windows 7 and with your indications  I manage to find and open `texdoc tikz`. It happens that the Manual I got was the same one for version 2.10.

Comment: @percusse I understand your comment about the *do-it-for-me*.

Comment: "Do-it-for-me" questions are also interesting for some users especially when no other questions are interesting.

Comment: After 4 answers and 5 question I've got the first downvote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 2cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 7.85cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 9cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}}
}
]
% The axes
\draw[help lines,->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) coordinate (xaxis);
\draw[help lines,->] (0,-1) -- (0,3) coordinate (yaxis);

% The path
\path[draw,line width=0.8pt,postaction=decorate] (1,0) node[below] {$\varepsilon$} -- (2,0) node[below] {$r$} arc (0:180:2) -- (-1,0) arc (180:0:1);

% The labels
\node[below] at (xaxis) {$x$};
\node[left] at (yaxis) {$y$};
\node[below left] {$O$};
\node at (0.5,1.2) {$C_{\varepsilon}$};
\node at (1.5,1.8) {$C_{r}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.75cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 2cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 14cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
mark=at position 15cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}}
}
]
% The axes
\draw[help lines,->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) coordinate (xaxis);
\draw[help lines,->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) coordinate (yaxis);

% The path
\path[draw,line width=0.8pt,postaction=decorate] (10:1) node[left] {$\varepsilon$} -- +(1,0) node[right] {$r$} arc (5:355:2) -- +(-1,0) arc (-10:-350:1);

% The labels
\node[below] at (xaxis) {$x$};
\node[left] at (yaxis) {$y$};
\node[below left] {$O$};
\node at (-0.9,1) {$\gamma_{\varepsilon}$};
\node at (1.4,1.9) {$\gamma_{r}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should use `\varepsilon` instead of `\epsilon` to exactly conform to the question's screenshot.

Comment: Which line width (`\path[draw,line width=1pt,postaction=decorate]` or `\path[draw,line width=0.3pt,postaction=decorate]`) is more usual when used in an article?

Comment: @AméricoTavares I finally used light rules for the axes and a line width of `0.8pt` for the path; I think this is a good balance.

Comment: @So does for me.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ thanks for uploading the images a while ago!

Answer (score 17):

For those who don't know how to compile PSTricks codes: Compile each of the following codes with either a combo (much faster) `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf` or a single run (much slower) of `xelatex` to get a PDF output. Once you get PDF images, you can import these PDF images within your main TeX input file using `\includegraphics{filename}`. The main TeX input file must be compiled with pdflatex (faster) or `xelatex` (much slower).

### First Diagram

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={2pt 5pt 13pt 13pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-0.25)(3,3)
% draw cartesian axes
\psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-3,-0.25)(3,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
% global setting
\psset{linecap=2}
% draw the outer arc
\psarc[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){2.5}{0}{60}
\psarc(0,0){2.5}{60}{180}
% draw the left line
\psline[ArrowInside=->](-2.5,0)(-1.5,0)
% draw the inner arc
\psarcn[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){1.5}{180}{150}
\psarcn(0,0){1.5}{150}{0}
% draw the right lint
\psline[ArrowInside=->](1.5,0)(2.5,0)
% draw label
\uput[60](2.5;60){$C_r$}
\uput[80](1.5;80){$C_\varepsilon$}
\uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Second Diagram

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={2pt 2pt 13pt 13pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\h{0.2}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
% draw cartesian axes
\psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
% global setting
\psset{linecap=2}
% declare nodes
\pnode(!2.5 2 exp \h\space 2 exp sub sqrt \h){A}
\pnode(!1.5 2 exp \h\space 2 exp sub sqrt \h){D}
\pnode(!2.5 2 exp \h\space 2 exp sub sqrt \h\space neg){B}
\pnode(!1.5 2 exp \h\space 2 exp sub sqrt \h\space neg){C}
% draw the outer arc
\psarc[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){2.5}{(A)}{60}
\psarc(0,0){2.5}{60}{(B)}
% draw the bottom line
\psline[ArrowInside=->](B)(C)
% draw the inner arc
\psarcn[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){1.5}{(C)}{300}
\psarcn(0,0){1.5}{300}{(D)}
% draw the top line
\psline[ArrowInside=->](D)(A)
% draw label
\uput[60](2.5;60){$\gamma_r$}
\uput[0](A){$r$}
\uput[150](1.5;150){$\gamma_\varepsilon$}
\uput[45](D){$\varepsilon$}
\uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Miscellaneous

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={2pt 2pt 13pt 13pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.1+0.1}{10}{
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
% draw cartesian axes
\psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
% global setting
\psset{linecap=1}
% declare nodes
\pnode(!2.5 2 exp \n\space 2 exp sub sqrt \n){A}
\pnode(!1.5 2 exp \n\space 2 exp sub sqrt \n){D}
\pnode(!2.5 2 exp \n\space 2 exp sub sqrt \n\space neg){B}
\pnode(!1.5 2 exp \n\space 2 exp sub sqrt \n\space neg){C}
%
\pscustom*[linecolor=lightgray]{\psarc(0,0){2.5}{(A)}{(B)}\psline(B)(C)\psarcn(0,0){1.5}{(C)}{(D)}\psline(D)(A)\closepath}
% draw the outer arc
\psarc[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){2.5}{(A)}{60}
\psarc(0,0){2.5}{60}{(B)}
% draw the bottom line
\psline[ArrowInside=->](B)(C)
% draw the inner arc
\psarcn[arcsepB=-3pt]{->}(0,0){1.5}{(C)}{300}
\psarcn(0,0){1.5}{300}{(D)}
% draw the top line
\psline[ArrowInside=->](D)(A)
% draw label
\uput[60](2.5;60){$\gamma_r$}
\uput[0](A){$r$}
\uput[150](1.5;150){$\gamma_\varepsilon$}
\uput[45](D){$\varepsilon$}
\uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The sad news is that `ArrowInside` is not available for `psarc`. :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why is it sad?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: As a result, we have to draw the middle arrow manually using two steps.

Comment: OK. I have entered your codes in TeXworks/TeXLive and "compiled" them with Typeset/XeLaTeX, because pdfLaTeX produced an error. Is that so? Or have I some malfunction in my installation?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: With an additional package, we can compile PSTricks code with pdflatex. But in my opinion, compiling each standalone diagram with `xelatex` (slower) or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (much faster) to get a PDF output and import these PDF diagrams in your main TeX input file compiled with pdflatex is a better approach compared to mix the diagram codes and text contents in a single TeX input file compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks again. I will await one or two days, hoping someone posts an answer using TikZ. If there is none I will accept your very good answer.

Comment: I had not yet scrolled all the way down, but upon seeing the animated ring I already knew who the author was ;)

Comment: `ArrowInside` also cannot accept `<-` and its variants (such as `|<-`, `|*-`, etc).

Comment: Can you explain the \pnode code? I see in the documentation:"
        \pnode(x,y ){name}
        This creates a zero dimensional node at (x,y ) "
I don't know the meaning of the expression in your code. can you clarify it? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here three solutions.

With Tikz we have several problems. First we need to use some angles to draw arcs and it's not easy if you don't know some mathematics notions like asin and atan2, then there is the problem to draw arrow at specific places.
The first solutions are based on tkz-euclide. The problem with tkz-eucide is the syntax base on pst-eucl and latex. I understand that a lot of users prefer to use only tikz. The main problem is that tkz-euclide is not very flexible and it's not easy to extend the commands. The last point is the notion of path, we can't use this notion as in tikz.

A fine solution is the last one based only on tikz.

It's possible to use tkz-euclide. The solution uses the same way as pst-eucl, because we can draw an arc from one point in the direction of another point. We don't need to calculate angles

1) I define four points B, C and D,E and I draw the arc with center O from B to C and from D to E.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,ymin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=5]
  \tkzDrawXY[noticks]
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
   \tkzDefPoint(.5,.2){B} \tkzDefPoint(.5,-.2){C}
   \tkzDefPoint(4,.2){D} \tkzDefPoint(4,-.2){E}  
  \tkzDrawArc[color=red,line width=1pt](O,B)(C)
  \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}};}]
    \tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate},color=red,line width=1pt](B,D E,C)
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,
     mark=at position .20 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}},
     mark=at position .70 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}};}]
    \tkzDrawArc[postaction={decorate},color=red,line width=1pt](O,D)(E)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2) Always with tkz-euclide but I don't use here the *decoration library* because it's not easy to place the arrow. Here I draw paths with the option `->`. I need to cut some paths in small paths

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,ymin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=5]
  \tkzDrawXY[noticks]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(3:4){D} \tkzDefPoint(90:4){M} \tkzDefPoint(270:4){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(-3:4){E}
  \tkzDefPoint[shift={(-3.5,0)}](3:4){B} \tkzDefMidPoint(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{B'}
  \tkzDefPoint[shift={(-3.5,0)}](-3:4){C} \tkzDefMidPoint(C,E) \tkzGetPoint{C'}

 \tkzDrawArc[color=red,line width=1pt](O,N)(E) 
 \tkzDrawArc[color=red,line width=1pt](O,B)(C)
 \tikzset{compass style/.append style={->}}
 \tkzDrawArc[color=red,line width=1pt](O,D)(M) 
 \tkzDrawArc[color=red,line width=1pt](O,M)(N) 

\tkzDrawSegments[color=red,line width=1pt,->](D,B' C,C')
\tkzDrawSegments[color=red,line width=1pt](B',B C',E)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

3) The last solution is to use tikz and to define a new macro to get polar coordinates of the last point. I named this macro `\pgfgetlastar` angle for a, and r for radius.

The code of the macro

```
\def\pgfgetlastar#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)/28.45274}
    \edef#1{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)}
    \edef#2{\pgfmathresult}%
}%
```

With `veclen` I get the length of OM if M is the last point used in the path and O the origin. atan2 gives the angle of OM with the horizontal axe.

Now the  next code is to use the macro in the options of a path

```
\tikzset{
    last polar/.code 2 args=
     {\pgfgetlastar{#1}{#2} }
    }
```

The macro in action : We draw an arc then a horizontal line. We determine the polar coordinates of the last point before to draw the last arc and the last line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[deco]     
\draw[red,postaction=decorate] 
      (4:4 cm) arc (4:356:4 cm) -- +(-3,0) [last polar={\r}{\a}] arc (\a:-360-\a:\r) --cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

We only need to define the decoration :

The complete code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfgetlastar#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)/28.45274}
    \edef#1{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)}
    \edef#2{\pgfmathresult}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    last polar/.code 2 args=
     {\pgfgetlastar{#1}{#2} }
    }

\tikzset{deco/.style= {decoration={markings,
      mark=at position .17 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}},
      mark=at position .51 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}},
      mark=at position .72 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}},
      mark=at position .95 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}
      }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[deco]     
\draw[red,postaction=decorate] 
      (4:4 cm) arc (4:356:4 cm) -- +(-3,0) [last polar={\r}{\a}] arc (\a:-360-\a:\r) --cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)  A very nice, helpful and pedagogical answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a complex mood today ;)

Here is a path drawn using small tikz library [`avoidpath`](https://github.com/kpym/tikz-avoidpath).

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{avoidpath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
      (-3,0) edge[-latex] node[at end, right]{$\operatorname{Re} z$} (3,0)
      (0,-3) edge[-latex] node[at end, right]{$\operatorname{Im} z$} (0,3)
      (0,0)  node[scale=3](O){.}
    ;
    \draw[avoid={pole={(O)}, neck=8mm}, with arrows, thick]
      (1.5,4mm)
        to[avoid={radius=2cm}]
      (1.5,-4mm)
        to[avoid={radius=1cm}]
      cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You use `node[scale=3](O){.}`. You must read [TikZ Nodes not exactly centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61343/14500)....

Comment: @PaulGaborit I know that a point of a non standard font can be badly centered and that you hate this, because we [have already discussed this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220760) ;)  But I like it because in general it works, it is simple, consistent and make smaller PDFs (single character against 4 cubic curves for a circle).

Comment: Ok. Sorry to ramble ... ;-)

Comment: No problem ! I always appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2):

For precision I computed internally in the tikz code angles and distances.
Needs at least PGS 3.0

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, very thick, decoration={markings, mark=at
      position 0.8 with {\arrow{>}}}]
      % coordinates for axis
    \coordinate (A) at (-8,0);
    \coordinate[label=$x$] (B) at (8,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,-8);
    \coordinate[label=$y$] (D) at (0,8);

    % axis
    \draw[-latex, line width=2pt, color=gray] (A)--(B);
    \draw[-latex, line width=2pt, color=gray] (C)--(D);
    % origin
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

    % eps, R small and large radius
    \def\eps{0.5} % epsilon
    \def\R{7} % epsilon
    \def\angeps{30} % angle for epsilon
    \def\angepsend{330} % angle for epsilon
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xeps{\eps*cos(\angeps)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yeps{\eps*sin(\angeps)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sinangeps{\yeps/\R}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angR{asin(\sinangeps)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angRend{360-\angR} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xR{\R*cos(\angR)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yR{\R*sin(\angR)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yRm{-\yR}


     % points for ends of small circle
     \coordinate (E) at (\xeps, \yeps);
     \coordinate (F) at (\xeps, -\yeps);

     % points for ends of large circle
     \coordinate (G) at (\xR, \yR);
     \coordinate (H) at (\xR, \yRm);


    % draw large circle with arrow inside the path
     \pgfmathsetmacro\angm{\angR+40}
    \draw[line width=2pt, ->]  (G) arc (\angR:\angm:\R);
    \draw[line width=2pt]  (G) arc (\angR:\angRend:\R);

    % draw small circle with arrow inside the path
    \def\angeps{-30} % angle for epsilon
    \def\angepsend{-180} % angle for epsilon
    \def\angepsendf{-330} % angle for epsilon
     \pgfmathsetmacro\angm{\angepsend-60}
     \draw[->, {->[length=5pt,bend]}, line width=2pt]  (F) arc (\angeps:\angm:\eps);
     \draw[line width=2pt]  (F) arc (\angeps:\angepsendf:\eps);


     % points for ends of small circle
     \pgfmathsetmacro\xepsd{\xeps-0.05};
     \pgfmathsetmacro\xRd{\xR+0.07};
     \coordinate (E2) at (\xepsd, \yeps);
     \coordinate (F2) at (\xepsd, -\yeps);

     % points for ends of large circle
     \coordinate (G2) at (\xRd, \yR);
     \coordinate (H2) at (\xRd, \yRm);


    \draw[postaction={decorate}, line width=2pt] (E2)--(G2);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}, line width=2pt] (H2)--(F2);


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Now the figure below:

[image: contour figure]