# Decorate contour with arrows in different directions

Tags: decorations

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78154/how-to-draw-these-closed-contours-diagrams-using-tikz-or-pstricks) post it is thoroughly explained how to decorate a contour with arrows. How can I do the same, but so that one contour has arrows in one direction, and the other contour has arrows in the opposite? The contours are in the same `tikzpicture` environment. Is it possible to define multiple instances of decorations, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple markings, and you can reverse either by drawing the path in the reverse direction or by defining the marking with reversed arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset
  {marking1/.style=
     {decoration=
        {markings,
         mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}}
        },
      postaction=decorate
     },
   marking1reversed/.style=
     {decoration=
        {markings,
         mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{<}}
        },
      postaction=decorate
     },
   marking2/.style=
     {decoration=
        {markings,
         mark=at position 0.33 with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth}},
         mark=at position 0.66 with {\arrow[line width=1pt,xscale=-1]{stealth}}
        },
      postaction=decorate
     }
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % a path with three sections
  \draw[marking1] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[marking1] (2,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw[marking1] (1,1) -- (0,0);
  % path drawn in the opposite direction, with the same marking
  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \draw[marking1] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[marking1] (1,1) -- (2,0);
    \draw[marking1] (2,0) -- (0,0);
  \end{scope}
  % the original path, but with another marking that reverses the arrows
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \draw[marking1reversed] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[marking1reversed] (2,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[marking1reversed] (1,1) -- (0,0);
  \end{scope}
  % the original path with a completely different marking
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
    \draw[marking2] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[marking2] (2,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[marking2] (1,1) -- (0,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I make it so the stealth arrow is reversed?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Using `xscale=-1`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I needed.