# How to draw the depicted contour in tikz?

Tags: diagrams, graphs, tikz-pic

How may I draw the following image as a tikzpicture?

[image: Image.]

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have some code to start with? If not, have a look at the [online Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev) and look for the `arc` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw these (closed contours) diagrams using TikZ or PSTricks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78154/how-to-draw-these-closed-contours-diagrams-using-tikz-or-pstricks)

Answer (score 1):

Here is at least something for you to play with. I haven't added everything from the image, you'll have to figure those out.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \def\xEpsilon{1}
  \def\cRadius{5}
  \coordinate (R) at (\cRadius,0);
  \coordinate (mR) at (-\cRadius,0);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (x) at ($(O)!0.6!(R)$);
  \coordinate (xme) at ($(x)+(-\xEpsilon,0)$);
  \coordinate (xpe) at ($(x)+(\xEpsilon,0)$);
  
  \begin{scope}[red,very thick]
    \draw (R) arc [start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=5]
    -- (O)
    -- (xme) arc [start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=\xEpsilon] node[pos=0.5,above,black] {$\gamma_{\varepsilon}$}
    -- cycle
    ;
  \end{scope}
  
  \draw ($(x)+(0,0.1)$)  -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$x$};
  \draw ($(R)+(0,0.1)$)  -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$R$};
  \draw ($(mR)+(0,0.1)$) -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$-R$};
  \draw ($(mR)+(-0.2,0)$) -- ($(R)+(0.2,0)$);
  \draw ($(O)+(0,-0.2)$) -- ++ (0,\cRadius + 0.4);
  
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```