# How to draw a 3D cube with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I want to draw a cube with TikZ. But when I make the edge thicker, the cube turns out to be:
[image]

and here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[black,line width=2pt] (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (0,2,0) --cycle;
\draw[black,line width=2pt] (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) --cycle;
\draw[black,line width=2pt] (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (2,2,2) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there any easy way to clip the “rag", or is there any other way to draw a cube?

Comment: There is this thread here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-a-3d-cube-with-tikz

Comment: More precisely, this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30102/216067 you can see that they used multiple scopes to defined 3 squares.

Comment: I add  `[line join=round]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` and fix the problem

Comment: There's also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21054/86

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this, as I can not see this solution in any of the other posts about cubes.

First draw the convex hull of the cube and then draw all other line segments with `line cap=round`, so that they do not protrude the border.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
\draw (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[line cap=round] (2,2,2) -- (0,2,2) (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A cube]

Drawing everything with `line join=round` will round over all corners of the cube, which dependent on use case might be acceptable. One advantage of this is that it does not matter in which order things are drawn.

**Edit:** Actually `line cap=round` is not needed at all. The default `line cap=butt` will not protrude. For other shapes with more acute outer angles, it might be needed to clip the additional line segments.

Comment: I added  `[line join=round]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` and achieved similar result. The difference is that all the corners are rounded.

Comment: +1 and for using the term `convex hull` one additional upvote in memory. :-)

Comment: A bit shorter code for drawing lines: `\draw   (0,2,0) -| (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -| (0,2,2) -- cycle 
        (0,2,2) -| (2,0,2)    (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0);`

Answer (score 1):

A cube with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (206,177.74) -- (253.94,129.8) -- (372.8,129.8) -- (372.8,241.66) -- (324.86,289.6) -- (206,289.6) -- cycle ; \draw  [line width=1.5]  (372.8,129.8) -- (324.86,177.74) -- (206,177.74) ; \draw  [line width=1.5]  (324.86,177.74) -- (324.86,289.6) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wish you a very happy and healthy new year...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Very kind friend. I give you and your family many wishes of happy new year.