# pgfplots: problem with "non-smooth" intersection of two lines' ends

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem like the one in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/bad-intersection-of-lines-in-tikz) concerning a `tikz` drawing but for a `pgfplots` plot. I want to create a plot that has one region filled without opacity and a neighboring one filled with opacity. The transparent region should be coated by a solid line. I managed to get pretty much what I want with this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{total.dos}
0  0  0  0  0   
1  2 -2  2 -2  
2  4 -4  4 -4  
3  2 -2  2 -2  
4  0  0  0  0 
5  1 -1  0  0 
6  2 -2  0  0 
7  1 -1  0  0 
8  0  0  0  0 
THIS WAS: TOTAL
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[comment chars={T}]{total.dos}\total

\begin{document}

% Set a filename for the next tikzpicture.
\tikzsetnextfilename{total_dos} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax=7, ymin=-7, xlabel={Energy [eV]}, ylabel={Intensity}, legend pos=north east]

\addplot [restrict x to domain=4:8, no markers, draw=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] table [x=0, y expr=\thisrowno{2} - \thisrowno{4}] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$2-4$}

\addplot [restrict x to domain=4:8, no markers, draw=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.3] table [x=0, y expr=\thisrowno{1} - \thisrowno{3}] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$1-3$}

\addplot [restrict x to domain=0:4, no markers, draw=blue , fill=blue] table [x=0, y=3] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$3$}

\addplot [restrict x to domain=0:4, no markers, draw=red, fill=red] table [x=0, y=4] {\total}; \addlegendentry{$4$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following picture:

[image]

The problem is the intersections of the coating lines' ends (those that come from the `draw=<color>` options). They are not smooth, but look like this:

[image]

My question: How can I get these things smooth?

Side note: I know that using the option `draw=none` gives the behaviour I want, but then I have no line surrounding the transparent region.

**Edit:**

I have stumbled upon something interesting: Adobe Acrobat X and SumatraPDF seem to handle the plots slightly differently. Acrobat cuts off the parts of the rightmost line endings that loom beyond the plotting domain (I don't know a better word for it) while SumatraPDF doesn't. Interestingly, this doesn't happen for the line endings on the left or in the middle (see picture above, which was made with Acrobat).

[image]

I'm not sure why this is so and whether it affects the possible solutions to my problems. Maybe this is an issue worth adressing in a different question? Or is this a mere PDF viewer question which shouldn't be asked here?

Comment: Would `line cap=round` as an option to the `\addplot` commands do what you want?

Comment: Also the `triangle 90 cap` arrow from `arrows` library can increase the blend feel.

Comment: @Jake: This option does improve the situation at the ends of the plot (though it's still not yet the optimum) but the intersection in the middle becomes worse than before.

Comment: @percusse: I'm pretty new to `tikz` and couldn't get your suggestion to work. I loaded `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in the preamble and tried to use the option `line cap=triangle 90 cap` after `addplot` but that didn't work. Was this all wrong? I expect it to look similar to `line cap=round`. But those are just workarounds. Will it be possible to make the lines really blend like in the `tikz` question I linked?

Comment: @Philipp: Doing this properly is really hard. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along/18717#18717 for some suggestions, but none of them are really the holy grail.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for the link. Since I'm new to `tikz` I hadn't realized that this might be such a difficult question. Youthful naivety is wonderful, isn't it ;)

Comment: Not to be rude but if you want to display the plot like the first picture is it not a bit 'overkill' to solve this minor issue? It is hardly visible with the naked eye in the first picture...

Comment: @WG-: It is admittedly a bit nit-picky, but I am quite a perfectionist when it comes to creating plots and documents. And apart from that I thought it to be an interesting problem whose solution might have helped me to learn more about how to do things with `tikz` and `pgfplots` in general.

Comment: Based on the edit, this question might be related?: [Incompatibility with TikZ and Mac OS X Preview](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126882/incompatibility-with-tikz-and-mac-os-x-preview) Maybe not. I'm not totally sure if they're related, but I thought that I would at least mention it here.

Answer (score 2):

Since `draw = none` gives the correct behavoir, we can simplify the problem.  Use `draw = none` around the red and blue regions in the `domain = 0:4`.  Now if we do `line join = round, line width = .08pt`, we can still see a border around dulled regions but we only have one connection of the lines to worry about.  However, since we used `line width = .08pt`, it is very hard to notice anything when zoomed in at `1600%`.

As you can see, we still have a border:

[image]

and zoomed at `1600%` we see no issues with the connection:

[image]

Would this be an acceptable solution for you?

---

Option 2:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8, 5);
    \filldraw[blue] (0, 0) -- (2, 4) -- (4, 0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .3, draw = blue]
    (4, 0) -- (6, 2) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8, -5);
    \filldraw[red] (0, 0) -- (2, -4) -- (4, 0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[red, opacity = .3, draw = red]
    (4, 0) -- (6, -2) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now all you need to do is draw the axis.

[image]

Then here is the intersection:

[image]

---

With darker outlines:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8, 5);
    \filldraw[blue] (0, 0) -- (2, 4) -- (4, 0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[blue, opacity = .3, draw = blue]
    (4, 0) -- (6, 2) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw[blue] (4, 0) -- (6, 2) -- (8, 0);
  \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8, -5);
    \filldraw[red] (0, 0) -- (2, -4) -- (4, 0) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[red, opacity = .3, draw = red]
    (4, 0) -- (6, -2) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red] (4, 0) -- (6, -2) -- (8, 0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, this will not do for my specific use case since I need a thicker line to coat the transparent region. This is because I might be required to use a very low opacity or leave out the transparent filling altogether, so that only the coating line remains as a visual guide for the transparent region.

Comment: @Philipp you can always play with the thickness to see what is thick enough without a visual displeasure.

Comment: That's true, but I'd need about ten times the thickness you used in your solution which is enough to cause "visual discontinuities" that vex me. Also, the ommitance of the line coating for the opaque region is not ideal when I use a thicker line width.

Comment: @Philipp there is always option 2.  Draw the pictures in TikZ.

Comment: Drawing it with TikZ might be an option, though I would prefer using pgfplots since I have a lot of data files which I want to plot with more or less the same code. Do you think an automated solution with TikZ that mitigates the problems described in my question will be feasible?

Comment: @Philipp have you considered trying gnuplot?  Or does that cause the same issue too?

Comment: I have considered matplotlib, which does indeed work :). But at the time of asking this question I didn't know my way around python.

Comment: @Philipp I use Python all the time for plots that wouldn't work in `LaTeX`.  You can save it as `pylab.savefig('name.eps', format = 'eps')` and then just use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Philipp I think data can be imported in `TikZ`.  I will have to look it up and see.

Comment: I think since version 1.2 matplotlib allows to export graphs as `pgf` code by including `matplotlib.use("pgf")` in the source code. This works quite good but with bigger plots this can run into memory issues.