# TikZ: bad line caps at the intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to draw two lines of different width intersecting at a point.  How to make slanted line's cap in triangle shape (or some other) so that  the point where two lines join does not look discontinuous?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[name path=al] (0,1.4)--(0,1.9);
\path [name path=al2] (.3,1.5)--++(150:.5);
\path [name intersections={of=al and al2,by=A}];
\draw [ultra thick](.3,1.5) --(A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are possible solutions at [Bad intersection of lines in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/bad-intersection-of-lines-in-tikz) but they deal with the lines with the same width.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the arrows.meta includes a Triangle Cap and Round Cap, your best bet is to draw too long and clip the excess.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[name path=al] (0,1.4)--(0,1.9);
\path [name path=al2] (.3,1.5)--++(150:.5);% will affect bounding box
\path [name intersections={of=al and al2,by=A}];
\begin{scope}
  \clip (current bounding box.south east) rectangle ($(A)+(0,1pt)$);% so as not to flatten the top
  \draw [ultra thick] (.3,1.5)--++(150:.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Let me remove `{scope}` environment and move `clip` command to the main frame. Am I right to expect that anything outside `\clip (current bounding box.south east) rectangle ($(A)+(0,1pt)$);`  will be clipped? If yes than why path `al`  is not getting clipped outside this rectangle?

Comment: Anything drawn before the \clip will stay.  Anything drawn after will be clipped.