# Newspaper layout

Tags: code-review

[image: compiled newspaper]

This is the template for my school newspaper that I maintain. It contains bits and pieces from everywhere (we all need to start start somewhere). I am aware that there are probably a lot that I can improve with this file. Right now, it's not pretty, but it works.

There are always two columns, 1 for horoscopes, 1 for news. It should be 1/3 page width and 2/3 page width (or slightly less for first column and the rest of width for second column - it seems too wide for me at 1/3).

It would be nice to have "Newspaper Name" vertically centered between top of page (with 0pt top margin) and on top of "Horoscopes" and "Breaking News!" and having a top and bottom padding.

So something like

```
{top page edge}
{blank line}
{blank line}
             NEWSPAPER NAME
{blank line}
{blank line}
Horoscopes    |   Breaking News!
Aquarius      |   Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
Lorem Ipsum   |   purus elit, ...
```

But this isn't important. It works well enough right now.

I compile with `xelatex newspaper.tex`.

All improvements welcome.

`newspaper.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.00in,paperwidth=8.50in,margin=0.70in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For resizebox
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\makeHeader}{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \resizebox{0.70 \linewidth}{!}{
                \uppercase{Newspaper Name}
            }
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \makeHeader

    \begin{minipage}[t][9in]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{spacing}{1}
            \section*{Horoscopes}
                \subsection*{Aquarius}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Pisces}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Aries}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Taurus}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Gemini}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Cancer}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Leo}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Virgo}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Libra}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Scorpio}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Sagittarius}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

                \subsection*{Capricorn}
                    Lorem Ipsum \\[-5pt]

        \end{spacing}
    \end{minipage}
%
    \hfill\vline\hfill
%
    \begin{minipage}[t][9in]{0.6\linewidth}
        \section{Breaking News!}
            \lipsum[1] \ldots\\[10pt]

        \section{Not So Breaking News}
            \lipsum[2] \ldots\\[10pt]

        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18360
        \section{Some Humour}
            Expand $(a+b)^n$:
            \begin{center}
                \newcount\mycntr
                \mycntr=-5
                \loop\advance\mycntr by 5
                    \ifnum\mycntr < 40
                        $(a\hskip\mycntr pt +\hskip\mycntr pt b)^n$\\
                \repeat
            \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Was cross-posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237474/newspaper-layout but I have deleted it because it is more appropriate here.

Comment: Is there only a single page or are there several pages? If so, how should the layout of the following pages look like?

Comment: @leandriis There's usally 2 pages (front and back) on single sheet of paper. The layout is the same for both sides (separated with `\clearpage`). Instead of horoscopes again, it would be "Daily quotes" or if the horoscopes are too long, they are split over both sides at Cancer/Leo.

Comment: "All improvements welcome" Then see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283119/11604).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "Newspaper Name" is repeated on the second page as well, a similar layout can be achieved using `fancyhdr` (for "Newspaper Name")  and `paracol` for the two column layout. With the latter, text that does not fit into the left column of the frst page will automatically continue in the left column on the second page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.00in,paperwidth=8.50in,margin=0.70in, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For resizebox
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{0.35}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[c]{\Huge\uppercase{Newspaper Name}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{35pt}


\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
   \section*{Horoscopes}
       \subsection*{Aquarius}
           Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Pisces}
           Lorem Ipsum

       \subsection*{Aries}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Taurus}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Gemini}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Cancer}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Leo}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Virgo}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Libra}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Scorpio}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Sagittarius}
           Lorem Ipsum 

       \subsection*{Capricorn}
           Lorem Ipsum 

   \section*{Daily Quotes}

   Your daily quote can be placed here.

  \switchcolumn
  \section{Breaking News!}
            \lipsum[1] 

   \section{Not So Breaking News}
            \lipsum[2] 

        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18360
   \section{Some Humour}
            Expand $(a+b)^n$:
            \begin{center}
                \newcount\mycntr
                \mycntr=-5
                \loop\advance\mycntr by 5
                    \ifnum\mycntr < 40
                        $(a\hskip\mycntr pt +\hskip\mycntr pt b)^n$\\
                \repeat
            \end{center}

    \section{another section}
        \lipsum[1-3]

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oooh `paracol` looks useful here. Is there a way to have the vertical line between the two columns to both have the same height?

Comment: Aparently this is not possible that easily using just `paracol`. At least I could not find any hint on that in the documentation.