# Reversed letters in a mathematical formula

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotating a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/rotating-a-letter)

For a work in logic, I need to write a iota upside down in a mathematical formula. I found this suggestion on the internet. First include [the usual math package] and the graphicx package

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amsthm, amssymb, mathrsfs,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in the preamble. Then use the command

```
\rotate{180}{$\iota$}
```

Indeed it works, but not perfectly: the axis of the rotation is at the basis of the letter (in 'normal' position). Hence, when I use this command, the reversed iota appears on a lower level than the text. I am thus not satisfied with this.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: `\rotate[c]{180}{$\iota$}`

Comment: For more information, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18157/215

Comment: Sorry, that should say `origin=c` not `c`...

Comment: @Seamus:OK, that's works perfectly with \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iota$}. Thanks!

Comment: This thread http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=5269 also talks of rotating iota and the solutions are different from yours.

Comment: @N.N. frabjous' `sideways` answer is different, but he also mentions exactly what I suggest. (He has since learned that `sideways` loads `graphicx` so the solution that uses that directly is probably better)

Comment: @Thomas: Nice to see that Seamus' answer helped! As this question is very similar to the linked question, which has a very good answer, I will close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Why not `\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\iota$}`. You might need to adjust the baseline using `\raisebox` and wrap the whole thing in `\ensuremath\mathrel{\text{..}}}` (`\text` to get the size correct in subscript)

Comment: @Stefan: Rotating a math letter is more difficult than a text letter, because the style/size must be passed into the `\rotatebox`. egreg's addresses this using `\mathpalette` in his answer.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't think it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Can we merge egreg's answer here into the question this is a dupe of? I think it does add important stuff about doing this in mathmode...

Comment: Ok, I reopen it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotated math with correct font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286050/rotated-math-with-correct-font-size)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A reference is [Rotating a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/rotating-a-letter), but rotating math symbols requires some more care:

```
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iota$}}
```

The `$` signs are necessary, since TeX is not in math mode when it processes the contents of the box to be rotated.

If the symbol is needed also in subscripts or superscripts, some more work is needed:

```
\newcommand{\rotatediota}{{\mathpalette\rotiota\relax}}
\newcommand{\rotiota}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$#1\iota$}}
```

Now `$\rotatediota_\rotatediota$` will have the desired result (**graphicx** is required, of course).

### Explanation

`\mathpalette\XXX\YYY` becomes

```
\mathchoice{\XXX\displaystyle\YYY}{\XXX\textstyle\YYY}
  {\XXX\scriptstyle\YYY}{\XXX\scriptscriptstyle\YYY}
```

and TeX will choose the right piece of code depending on the current math style. So it suffices to define `\XXX` with two arguments, the first of which is a math style declaration. Here we don't have a "variable" part, so the second argument to `\rotiota` is just `\relax` (it could be any token, since it's eventually discarded; `\mathpalette` requires *two* arguments, to begin with).

The extra group around `\mathpalette\rotiota\relax` is to allow for a simpler syntax when the symbol must be used in a subscript.

If it has to be a relation symbol, don't forget to put it into `\mathrel`, or modify the definition to

```
\newcommand{\rotatediota}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rotiota\relax}}
```

### Remarks

This is also a good candidate for a command to be declared robust, if used extensively in captions or headings:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rotatediota}{...}
```

or, loading **etoolbox**,

```
\newrobustcmd{\rotatediota}{...}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\reflectbox{$\in$}
```

You can use a reflectbox as well.

```
\reflectbox{$\iota$}
```

Comment: The question is about rotating, not reflecting around the y-axis, which is what `\reflectbox` does. You can reflect around the x-axis with a combination of `\scalebox` and `\raisebox`, though.

Comment: perhaps you're not aware symmetry about an axis - which is exactly what rotate 180 means.

Comment: I know enough math to distinguish between a direct (positive determinant) isometry from an inverse one. A rotation is direct, a reflection is inverse. Try rotating and reflecting a P in order to appreciate the difference.

Comment: Yet you missed his constant 180, not theta or a variable. He won't care how smart unless you help him with his problem, or not. Your morphisms and mine are equivalent, in the asker's case, up to isomorphism.

Comment: No; reflecting or rotating a iota gives different results.

Comment: No egreg, while you were so busy trying to correct superfluous math you neglected he wanted a transform that worked for this specific case. If you mapped them out the domain to range is bijective for his case.  That makes it an answer he can use. That's all he wanted. Not a category lesson.

Comment: An image is worth more than a thousand words [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vfah.png)