# How to rotate a big mathematical operator?

Tags: math-operators, unicode-math, rotating, stix2

I would like to rotate the `\bigcupdot` operator, provided by the STIX2 Math font, by 180 degrees about its center. I tried the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$[\bigcupdot]\ [\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\bigcupdot}}]$
\end{document}
```

The result was this:

[image: A failed attempt to rotate the bigcupdot operator]

Why didn't the rotated version typeset? How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know why LuaTeX doesn't throw an error, but the argument of `\rotatebox` is _always_ text. You need `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\bigcupdot$}`.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. Strangely, if you replace `\bigcupdot` by `\cupdot` in my original code, the rotated version does typeset, without the dollar signs.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there I don't use Unicode engines unless my life depends on it...  `;-)`

Comment: it is a side effect of `unicode-math` that `\bigcupdot` simply expands to `⨃` which works in text given a suitable font.

Comment: Isn't this just the same as `\bigcapdot` ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: STIX2 doesn't have `\bigcapdot` (unlike `MnSymbol` and `fdsymbol`).

Comment: @SandyG -- What!!!  It's supposed to.  I'll check, and then submit a bug report as appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton no unicode character

Comment: @barbarabeeton Also no `\bigcapplus`, which would also be helpful. (`\biguplus` is available.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Technically `\bigcupdot` doesn't "expand". `latexdef -t lualatex -p unicode-math bigcupdot ⟹ "\bigcupdot: the character ⨃"`

Comment: @user202729 sorry "is" not "expands to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$[\bigcupdot]$  [\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\bigcupdot$}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\rotatebox` typesets its argument in text mode and you would get “Missing $” errors with XeLaTeX, but nothing in LuaLaTeX (unless the current ***text*** font happens to have the character.

Anyway, using `$\bigcupdot$` isn't enough.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigcapdot}{}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\bigcapdot@\relax}\displaylimits
}
\newcommand{\bigcapdot@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1\bigcupdot$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]$

\[
[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]
\]

\end{document}
```

Here `twocolumn` is just to make a smaller picture.

[image]

---

Why just adding `$` around `\bigcupdot` isn't enough? Look at the comparison below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigcapdot}{}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\bigcapdot@\relax}\displaylimits
}
\newcommand{\bigcapdot@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1\bigcupdot$}}}%
}
\makeatother

% for comparison
\newcommand{\simplebigcapdot}{\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\bigcupdot$}}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Scaling}

$[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]$
$\scriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]$
$\scriptscriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]$

\[
[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot]
\]

\subsubsection*{Not scaling}

$[\bigcupdot][\simplebigcapdot]$
$\scriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\simplebigcapdot]$
$\scriptscriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\simplebigcapdot]$

\[
[\bigcupdot][\simplebigcapdot]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need other flipped symbols:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigcapdot}{}{%
  \genericbigopflip{\bigcupdot}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigcapplus}{}{%
  \genericbigopflip{\biguplus}%
}

\newcommand{\genericbigopflip}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\bigcapdot@{#1}}\displaylimits
}
\newcommand{\bigcapdot@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1#2$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot][\biguplus][\bigcapplus]$
$\scriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot][\biguplus][\bigcapplus]$
$\scriptscriptstyle[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot][\biguplus][\bigcapplus]$

\[
[\bigcupdot][\bigcapdot][\biguplus][\bigcapplus]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote: "`$\bigcupdot$` isn't enough". Why is it not enough?

Comment: Actually you don't get errors with LuaTeX, which is what puzzled me to start with...

Comment: @EvanAad I added a comparison between the two approaches. You judge.

Comment: @campa Oh, yes, the bizarre decision of LuaTeX to allow math symbols not in $. LuaTeX tries to get the character from the text font (and doesn't find it, of course).

Comment: @egreg Isn't it unicode-math developers choice to define it by letting it to a character instead of `\Umathchardef` it? The latter case I believe should give an error when used in text mode.

Comment: Remark, if correct scaling is needed, it's more user-friendly to use `\text` instead of `\mathpalette` as in this other answer of egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286069/250119

Comment: @user202729 In (the current version of) LuaTeX, if a `\Umathchardef` token is found in text mode, all the information is ignored except for the code point and the character with that code point is typeset from the current font.

Sometimes it's easier to use `\text`, sometimes it isn't.