# Reverse an existing big math operator keeping same functionality (such as limits)

Tags: math-mode, graphics, amsmath, math-operators

> I would like to define an operator `\rsum` which has all the same functionality of `\sum` with the only difference being that `\rsum` displays a mirrored image of the sigma glyph.

I have found the following questions which each address a part of what I want:

[How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined)

[Reversed letters in a mathematical formula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22961/reversed-letters-in-a-mathematical-formula)

However, I'm having difficulty in marrying the two accepted answers into a single solution. How would I go about accomplishing this? (An answer to this question doesn't necessarily have to use the approaches in the other questions.)

I don't anticipate using custom fonts for this purpose, but the capability to do so wouldn't be unappreciated (if not by me by someone in the future, I'm sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's almost automatic. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rsum}{\DOTSB\rsum@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\rsum@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\rsum@@\relax}}
\newcommand{\rsum@@}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\sum@$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\rsum_{i=1}^n
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^n\rsum_{i=1}^n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main idea is to reflect the symbol in the appropriate math style; some bells and whistles for `amsmath` have been added.

Should you need also rotated versions, here they are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rsum}{\DOTSB\rsum@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\rsum@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\rsum@@\relax}}
\newcommand{\rsum@@}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\sum@$}}

\newcommand{\usum}{\DOTSB\usum@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\usum@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\udsum@@{90}}}
\newcommand{\dsum}{\DOTSB\dsum@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\dsum@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\udsum@@{-90}}}
\newcommand{\udsum@@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum@$}%
    \hbox to \wd\z@{%
      \hss
      \resizebox{\ifx\displaystyle#1\else0.9\fi\wd\z@}{\dimexpr\ht\z@}{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{#2}{$\m@th#1\sum@$}%
      }%
      \hss
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\rsum_{i=1}^n
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^n\rsum_{i=1}^n
\]

\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\usum_{i=1}^n
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^n\usum_{i=1}^n
\]

\[
\sum_{i=1}^n\dsum_{i=1}^n
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^n\dsum_{i=1}^n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't imagine a sleeker approach showing up. But I'll hold my breath to accept this just yet. Thanks!

Comment: May be in `r` version `\rotatebox{180}` instead of `\reflectbox` because of the width of different lines? And similar, in the `u` and `d` versions, may be those should be a rotation of a reflectbox (or a reflectbox of your rotation)?

Comment: @Manuel I tried the 180 degree rotation, but it's unsatisfying because of the different thickness of the horizontal strokes. All variations are possible, but the 90 degree rotated symbols are just a joke.

Comment: It might look stupid for Sigma, but someone might find it useful for a different symbol. I can usually alter a few lines of code from this site to tailor it for my needs. So, extra generality never hurts.