# Error using the package makeidx

Tags: packages, errors, amsmath, indexing, incompatibility

My index is working smoothly with the command

```
\makeindex
```

alone. However, when I put

```
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
```

compilation gives two errors as

```
1. Command \see already defined.
\newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}
2. Command \printindex already defined.
...command\printindex{\@input@{\jobname.ind}}
```

Packages I am using are:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}%
\usepackage{amsmath,chemarrow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,thmtools}% 
\usepackage{amsmath,diagrams}%
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}%
\usepackage{amsfonts,eucal}%
\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{xy}%
\usepackage{bez123,calc,curves,ebezier,epic,eepic,multiply,rotating}%
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{manfnt}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{slashed}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
```

I am curious where is the clash. I am using MikTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Which class do you use? What happens, when you put `\usepackage{makeidx}` at the beginning? Perhaps that sequence shows you, which package makes the problem. Why do you load amsmath  5 times ans amsfonts 3 times? (That's not the problem, I just recognized it).

Comment: the facilities for indexes are already built into ams document classes -- `amsart`, `amsbook` and `amsproc`.  if you are using one of these document classes, or another built on top of one of these, you will get the errors you report.  this is well documrnted.  you need to say what class you are using, not just the packages.  (if you *are* using an ams class, `amsmath`, `amsfonts` and `amsthm` are also built in, so need not be specified.)

Comment: According to different advice I found on the internet I added an additional \usepackage{amsmath,something}. Later I have not checked if any of them were redundant. So I left them as they are, lest I lose some ornamental fascility. They are couple of lines. Hence, I understand that adding \usepackage{makeidx} does not add to options that I might have. So, thanks.

Comment: Adding to @knut's comments about your use of packages, there's no need to add `%` at the end of all these lines. For more information, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines.

Answer (score 8):

the facilities for indexes are already built into ams document classes -- `amsart`, `amsbook` and `amsproc`.

if you are using one of these document classes, or another built on top of one of these, you will get the errors you report. this is well documented.

you need to say what class you are using, not just the packages. (if you are using an ams class, `amsmath`, `amsfonts` and `amsthm` are also built in, so need not be specified.)