# How do I enforce a font size on a newly-defined symbol while using it in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I've defined the following new commands:

```
\newcommand{\atoi}{\mathrm{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iotaup$}}}
\newcommand{\scriptatoi}{{\scriptsize{\mathrm{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iotaup$}}}}}
```

to use in this formula (and other formulas in which $\atoi$ occurs):

```
$\psi^{\scriptatoi x\phi}_{z}  \equiv \exists y(\phi^y_x \:\&\: \forall u(\phi^u_x \rightarrow u\!=\!y) \:\&\: \psi^y_z)$
```

When I typeset the LaTeX source file using pdflatex (from TeXLive
2010), I get the following complaint:

LaTeX Font Warning: Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode on input
line 352.

If, however, I write the following line instead:

```
$\psi^{\atoi x\phi}_{z}  \equiv \exists y(\phi^y_x \:\&\: \forall u(\phi^u_x \rightarrow u\!=\!y) \:\&\: \psi^y_z)$
```

the atoi character appears full size, not superscript size.

Writing

```
$\psi^{\scriptsize\atoi x\phi}_{z}  \equiv \exists y(\phi^y_x \:\&\: \forall u(\phi^u_x \rightarrow u\!=\!y) \:\&\: \psi^y_z)$
```

again yields the desired typeset result, and again yields the LaTeX
Font Warning.

How can I do what I want, that is, get my new symbol in an appropriate
superscript size when using it in a superscript, while respecting the
font restrictions of math mode?

Comment: As far as I know, the command is called `\scriptstyle`. Generally, `\...size` applies to textmode, whereas `\...style` applies to mathmode.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/rotating-a-letter

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and especially for the pointer to the fine exposition of rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this construction is simple enough that you can forget about redefining it for multiple sizes.
instead, use the `\text` facility of `amsmath`:

```
\renewcommand{\atoi}{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iotaup$}}}
```

this can be used both in the "main line" and in super/subscripts of any level, and it should produce the desired result.

(the definition of `\text` is based on `\mathchoice`; take a look at `amstext.sty` -- it isn't very long.)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the command `\mathchoice` that chooses the correct math size:

```
\newcommand\atoistyle[1]{\mbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$#1\iotaup$}}}
\newcommand\atoi{\mathchoice
  {\atoistyle\displaystyle}
  {\atoistyle\textstyle}
  {\atoistyle\scriptstyle}
  {\atoistyle\scriptscriptstyle}
}
```

As egreg points out in the chat, this is the job of the command `\mathpalette` [(see details here)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393/the-mysteries-of-mathpalette/34412#34412), so the following is an exact equivalent of the preceeding:

```
\newcommand\atoistyle[2]{\mbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$#1\iotaup$}}}
\newcommand\atoi{\mathpalette\atoistyle\relax}
```

Answer (score 2):

use it this way:

```
\newcommand\atoi{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\iotaup$}}
\newcommand\scriptatoi{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\scriptstyle\iotaup$}}
```

in math mode the font style is `scriptstyle`