# Reverse a glyph?

Tags: rotating, characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotating a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/rotating-a-letter)

Given any printable glyph, is there some way to reverse it along the vertical (or any other) axis? So that, for instance, a sans-serif **d** would appear something like a **b**? (But for more complex glyphs than that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods above are right and just to add using `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<text>}` from the same `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
d \scalebox{-1}[1]{d}

c \scalebox{-1}[1]{c}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
text \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]  \node[rotate=-180,xscale=1,yscale=-1] (char) {text};
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not robust but still does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `reflectbox` command of `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
d \reflectbox{d}

e \reflectbox{e}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\reflectbox` from the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
d \psscalebox{-1 1}{d}

e \psscalebox{-1 1}{e}
\end{document}
```