# How to rotate text inline?

Tags: rotating, inline

I used the rotating package to rotate the symbol 90 positive degrees and that worked well. But I also want to rotate it 270 positive degrees and then it ends up hanging down on the line below. How can one rotate symbols any degree while it stays on the same line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to [Rotating a letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18157). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 163):

You can use `\rotatebox` (from the `graphicx` package) with the `origin=c` option instead; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

A\rotatebox{90}{B}C

A\rotatebox{270}{B}C

A\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{B}C

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that the `90` inside of `\rotatebox{90}` means `rotate 90°` **counter-clockwise**. The whole thing, `\rotatebox{90}{B}` means "rotate the letter **B** 90°". It gives us something similar to the Unicode character **ᗶ**, which is `U+15F6` or maybe `U+15F7`

Comment: `\rotate{270}{B}` rotates the letter `B` three quarter turns anti-clockwise? `270°` is three times `90°`?

Answer (score 6):

You can also rotate the whole font like this:

```
\setCJKmainfont[Script=CJK,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs,BoldFont=KAIU.TTF,
       ItalicFont=DFT_Z3.TTC,BoldItalicFont=DFT_L5.TTC,
       SmallCapsFont=DFT_TX3.TTC]{HANAMINA.TTF}
```

Comment: In English, what does that code do? For example, what is the fully spelled out English phrase for `CJK` inside of `Script=CJK`?

Comment: @IdleCustard CJK=ChineseJapaneseKorean