A command for typing ʍ in LaTeX
I need to type ʍ in LaTeX, but ʍ doesn't look really nice typed like this.
So, my question is: is tere a code that produces rotated W for 180°?

are you looking for a font that has  ʍ   or are you looking to simply rotate a W with \rotatebox{180}{W} ?

You can directly type this letter in unicode-aware engines like lualatex or xelatex. How it will look like will depend on the font. Choose one you like.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18160/36296 if you want to rotate the letter

tipa package for pdflatex has \textturnw

There is an IPA symbol, ʍ, and some font families (including Computer Modern) provide it with the tipa package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ʍ}{\textturnw}

\begin{document}

wʍ

\end{document}


Otherwise, you can rotate:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\turnedw}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{w}}

\newunicodechar{ʍ}{\turnedw}

\begin{document}

wʍ

\end{document}

The output is the same.
